# lazy evaluation and late binding of python?

Tags: python, lambda, lazy-evaluation, late-binding

when is lazy evaluation?  (generator, if, iterator?),
when is late binding? (closure, regular functions?)

```
    a = [1,2,3,4]
    b = [lambda y: x for x in a] 
    c = (lambda y: x for x in a) #lazy evaluation
    d = map(lambda m: lambda y:m, a) #closure
    for i in b:
        print i(None)
    # 4 4 4 4
    for i in c:
        print i(None)
    # 1 2 3 4 
    for i in d:
        print i(None)
    # 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Well, info you are using python3, map returns an iterator, which is why d and c are the same

Comment: i'm using python2.7，d is  <type 'list'>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like homework, so I won't just give you the answers. Here are two functions that you can step through and see how the values change.

```
def make_constants_like_generator():
    def make_constant(x):
        def inner(y):
            return x
        return inner
    results = []
    for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
        results.append(make_constant(i))
        for f in results:
            print f(None)
    return results

def make_constants_like_list():
    x = None
    results = []
    for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
        x = i
        def inner(y)
            return x
        results.append(inner)
        for f in results:
            print f(None)
    return results
```

Lazy evaluation is waiting until the last possible moment to evaluate an expression. The opposite is eager evaluation. The generator expression is lazy, it does nothing until it is iterated. The list expression is eager, as soon as it is encountered, the list is filled with values.

Early and late binding relate to how the system determines what a name refers to. All names in python are late bound. Combined with lazy evaluation that means that what a name is bound to can change before expressions that use it are evaluated

```
def map(func, iter):
    return (func(val) for val in iter)
```

Comment: i want know more about lazy evaluation ,late binding,and The result of map confused me

Comment: Maybe you mean this?  （make_constants_like_list）
def make_constants_like_list():
    results = []
    for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
        def inner(y):
            return i
        results.append(inner)
    return results

Comment: No, I specifically mean these to be lengthy, so they can be stepped through and/or have prints added

Comment: I mean, in function inner(like_list) return x, should be return i

Comment: Oops, no, fixed

Comment: I think b depends on late binding，It does not depend on lazy evaluation or early evaluation!    c depends on lazy evaluation(and it's late binding too).      and how is map implemented? i'm very confused about map's result!

Comment: Everything in python is late bound, which means *what it is bound to* can change